# Take in integer and string using input() and check for conditions

Tags: python

I needed help with this problem here in python:

Write a program which accepts an integer N and N strings each on a newline. Check for the below conditions and perform the respective operations:
The string contains only one word then capitalize the whole string
The string contains exactly 2 words capitalize only the first character of each word
The string contains more than two words toggle case of the string
Your task is to print each string in a newline after performing the respective operations.

```
Input Format:
The first line will contain an integer N, specifying the number of strings
The next N lines will contain one string each

Output Format:
String after performing the respective operation in a newline.

Example #1:
Input:
3            #number of input words
Hello        #1st input
My name is   #2nd input
adam smith   #3rd input

Output:
HELLO
mY NAME IS
Adam smith
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AdamStrauss I just had a day of class in python. Just 1. and they wanted this as assignment. I did my RnD but failed to come up with a solution as I'm unaware of most if the keywords and functions. I have like 10 different questions like this. A few I solved and a few that I can't because I'm not able to figure out. The first question was to create a function to do some calculation and return the value. And functions were not covered in the class. Hell I didn't know even how to create a function. No issues, I learned it on my own and figured out the solution. But this one I'm unable to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work:

```
num=int(input())
words=[]
for a in range(0,num):
  words.append(input())

for word in words:
  if len(word.split())==1:
    print(word.upper())
  elif len(word.split())==2:
    print(word.title())
  elif len(word.split())>2:
    print(word.swapcase())
```

if you are trying to attempt a HackerRank challenge or any other code challenge, i would strongly recommend first building small programs then attempting those.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would have to look through a multi-line string to get the input.

So a sample string would look something like:

```
sample = """
3
Hello
My name is
adam smith
"""
```

Now, to find the number of words in one line of each string...
There is a built-in string function called split(), but I'm going to do the basic version:

```
def toWords(string):
    newlist = []  # create a list we can add things to with ".append()"
    newstr = ''  # initial string
    for i in string:
        if i == ' ':  # When we come across a space
            newlist.append(newstr)  # Add what's been accumulated to list
            newstr = '' # Start over
        else:
            newstr += i # Accumulate
    if newstr:
        newlist.append(newstr)
    return newlist  # Finally, return the value
```

We also need a way to split up the multi-line string:

```
my_list = sample.split('\n') # where '\n' is the newline character
```

Last, we add the rules:

```
def all(string):
    acc = ""  #acc for accumulator
    my_list = string.split('\n')
    toggle = 1
    number = int(my_list[0])
    for i in my_list[1:]:
        if len(toWords(i)) == 1:
            acc += toWords(i)[0].lower() + ' '
        elif len(toWords(i)) == 2:
            acc += toWords(i)[0].capitalize() + toWords(i)[1].capitalize() + ' '
        else:
            for char in i:
                toggle = toggle * -1
                if toggle == 1:
                   acc += char
            acc += ' '
     return acc
```